# Can Anyone point me to a Android Market catalog or application list

Tags: android, list, catalog, marketplace

I'm up and running in Eclipse, have worked through several tutorials and would like to start developing my first marketable app.  Is there anyplace I can find a comprehensive list or catalog of what's available on the Android marketplace?  I'd hate to waste a lot of development time building an app that has twelve free versions already available.

Answer (score 1):

Two sites that maintain such a listing are:

http://www.androlib.com

http://www.cyrket.com

Unfortunately, the Android Market site is quite rudimentary for such a need.

Answer (score 1):

And since February 2011, of course, http://market.android.com

Answer (score 0):

Also, be aware that Amazon is getting into the game with the [Amazon Appstore for Android](https://developer.amazon.com/home.html) (although this isn't in operation yet, as of 1st March 2011).  No list of apps yet, but I would keep an eye on this over the next year or so to see if anything becomes of it, as Amazon have a good reliable route to market for most consumers.